# Fabricjs does not display the controls correctly

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

If you change the size/position of the object not manually, but in the code, the controls may not be displayed correctly. For example, I created a square and moved it. If you move the mouse to its old place, the cursor will change and if you start moving the object will move but relative to its new position. If you click on its new location, nothing will happen. This is corrected if you click on a different place on the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `.setCoords()` on your object after changing values like position programmatically.

See the following:

http://fabricjs.com/fabric-gotchas
https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/When-to-call-setCoords

Comment: Yes, this also works, but together with discardActiveObject()

Answer (score 0):

This function helped me:

```
function Moved() {
    canvas.discardActiveObject();
    canvas.setActiveObject(object)
    canvas.discardActiveObject();
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

It should be called at the end of initialization of the canvas and objects and after each change of location.
It is also better to use renderAll() instead of requestRenderAll() wherever possible.